# memcmp filter similar to LIKE %

Tags: anchor, getprogramaccounts, memcmp

say i have a PDA

```
struct Foo {
  created_at: i64
}
```

with a `created_at` unix sec timestamp field (ex: `1690004000`). I want to filter all PDAs that were created in `1690000000`. as far as i know ints are store in bs58 encoded little endian, which the bs58 encoding kind of ruins things. I tried doing

```
const bytes = anchor.utils.bytes.bs58.encode(new anchor.BN(1690000000).toBuffer("le", 8)).slice(0, 4)

const accts = await program
    .account.foo.all(
      [
        {
          memcmp: {
            offset: 8,
            bytes,
          }
        }
      ]
    )
```

but got nothing. is there a way to go about doing this or will i need to store the time epoch (`1690000000` ) as a separate field in the PDA and do an exact filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`base58` is simply the encoding used when sending data, it doesn't affect things otherwise.

Your logic is correct and I managed to reproduce the client code and I can confirm this works:

```
 // number to bs58, but a little different than your version
const ntobs58 = x => anchor.utils.bytes.bs58.encode(new anchor.BN(x).toArrayLike(Buffer, 'le', 8));

const accts = await pg.program.account.newAccount.all([
        {
          memcmp: {
            offset: 8,
            bytes: ntobs58(n), // n is a timestamp
          }
        }
      ]);
```

This is how my accounts looks like:

```
#[account]
pub struct NewAccount {
    created_at: i64
}
```

Double check that:

- you're encoding the `bytes` correctly, I see you have a `.slice(0, 4)`, I think that's the problem. Trimming a `base58` string makes it invalid.
- your account has indeed a single field (`created_at`) or, in case you have multiple fields, that this field is the first one in the byte representation of the account.